# Как правильно

Tags: грамотная-речь

Получила специальность "бухгалтер-финансист" или Получила специальность бухгалтера-финансиста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оба варианта верны. На Ваш выбор.

Comment: А как быть с кавычками?

Comment: В деловой речи принято писать с кавычками,в разговорной лучше второй вариант
http://uloblsud.ru/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=1457    11. Название специальности пишется в кавычках с маленькой буквы, например: прошел обучение по специальности «электрик и электросварщик"

Answer (score 1):

Оба выражения возможны, при этом первое более формально (ссылка на наименование специальности по перечню) и обязывает к точности.

Comment: А как быть с кавычками